# How to set up and run StandfordCoreNLP java program

Tags: java, nlp

After added StandfordCoreNLP library in Netbeans I am trying to run NLP java program but still it gives me Error About Packages.

> Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'stfNLP'
>   
>   Information:javac 1.8.0_201 was used to compile java sources Information:14/6/19 2:38 PM - Build completed with 21 errors and 3 warnings in 45 s 523 ms 
>   
>   Warning:java: source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

Already added Dependency and Library to netbeans

Comment: Describe steps to reproduce your issue and show error messages (as text)

Comment: Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'stfNLP'
Information:javac 1.8.0_201 was used to compile java sources
Information:14/6/19 2:38 PM - Build completed with 21 errors and 3 warnings in 45 s 523 ms
Warning:java: source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

Comment: You can [edit] your question, don't post error messages/code/etc. in comments